# replace a key value pair from a GET request without mutating the original JSON

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I have a task to return some an object by name of recipe and include a list of it's ingredients and also an object that replaces the instructions with a key value pair of `"numSteps": count_of_instruction_steps`. I am having a hard time with removing the key of "instructions" for the result.

This is the `.json` file of recipes:

```
{
  "recipes": [
    {
      "name": "scrambledEggs",
      "ingredients": [
        "1 tsp oil",
        "2 eggs",
        "salt"
      ],
      "instructions": [
        "Beat eggs with salt",
        "Heat oil in pan",
        "Add eggs to pan when hot",
        "Gather eggs into curds, remove when cooked",
        "Salt to taste and enjoy"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "garlicPasta",
      "ingredients": [
        "500mL water",
        "100g spaghetti",
        "25mL olive oil",
        "4 cloves garlic",
        "Salt"
      ],
      "instructions": [
        "Heat garlic in olive oil",
        "Boil water in pot",
        "Add pasta to boiling water",
        "Remove pasta from water and mix with garlic olive oil",
        "Salt to taste and enjoy"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "chai",
      "ingredients": [
        "400mL water",
        "100mL milk",
        "5g chai masala",
        "2 tea bags or 20 g loose tea leaves"
      ],
      "instructions": [
        "Heat water until 80 C",
        "Add milk, heat until 80 C",
        "Add tea leaves/tea bags, chai masala; mix and steep for 3-4 minutes",
        "Remove mixture from heat; strain and enjoy"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The task is the following:
A GET request to `http://localhost:3000/recipes/details/garlicPasta` should return, if recipe exists, this `.json`:

```
Response body (JSON):
{
    "details":
        {
            "ingredients": [
                "500mL water",
                "100g spaghetti",
                "25mL olive oil",
                "4 cloves garlic",
                "Salt"
            ],
            "numSteps":5
        }
}
Status: 200
```

And should return this if it does not exist:

```
Response body (JSON): {}
Status: 200
```

This is what I am actually getting:

```
{
  name: "garlicPasta",
  ingredients: [
  "500mL water",
  "100g spaghetti",
  "25mL olive oil",
  "4 cloves garlic",
  "Salt"
 ],
 instructions: {
  numSteps: 5
  }
}
```

My code is the following:

```
app.get('/recipes/details/:name', (req, res) => {
  let count = 0
  const numSteps = {}
  const recipe = recipes.find(r => r.name === req.params.name)
  const instructions = recipes.map(r => {
    if(r.name === req.params.name){
      for(let instruction of r.instructions){
          count += 1
      }
    }
  })
  recipe.instructions = {"numSteps": count}
  res.status(200).send(recipe);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't try to return a modified "recipe" object since the shape of the response you need is different.  You can use your existing code to find the correct recipe, and then just create a new object with the response properties you want.  Note that you can just use recipe.instructions.length to know how many steps there are.

```js
app.get('/recipes/details/:name', (req, res) => {
  let count = 0;
  const recipe = recipes.find(r => r.name === req.params.name);
  
  const output = {
    details: {
      ingredients: recipe.ingredients,
      numSteps: recipe.instructions.length
    }
  };
  
  res.status(200).send(output);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating the `details` property, and you're adding an `instructions` property in the result that you don't want.

There's no need to loop to count `numSteps`, you can just use `r.instructions.length`. And once you find the recipe with `recipes.find()`, you don't need another loop to find the recipe name.

You're not checking whether the recipe can be found, so that you return `{}` in that case.

```js
app.get('/recipes/details/:name', (req, res) => {
  const recipe = recipes.find(r => r.name === req.params.name);
  let result = {};
  if (recipe) {
    result.details = {
      ingredients: recipe.ingredients,
      numSteps: recipe.instructions.length
    };
  }
  res.status(200).send(recipe);
})
```